# How to connect to wifi from new antergos install using terminal only?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, command-line

I have just recently obtained an old Macbook and installed antergos on it. I noticed that the LiveUSB for antergos didn't have wifi connectivity (i.e. there was no wifi icon in the gnome system tray). I thought that wifi functionality would be installed, but it hasn't been. Now what? I can verify that this computer has a wireless interface, because it worked fine on this pc when I had fedora installed on it previously. What can I do to fix this? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Nmtui, nmcli, wcid, iwconfig.

Comment: Find out what driver fedora uses and use the same on antergos.

Comment: What was the output of iwconfig? Is there a `wlan0` interface? (If not, the driver is missing for some reason). Is `iw` installed? Does something like `iw wlan0 scan` give output? (If yes, the driver works correctly). Is your WLAN encrypted and wpasupplicant installed?